# Matlab Coder; Subscripting into an mxArray is not supported

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, matlab-coder

Using matlab coder, I get `Subscripting into an mxArray is not supported.` error in the following function:

```
function net = mlpunpak(net, w)
% Check arguments for consistency
errstring = consist(net, 'mlp');
if ~isempty(errstring);
    error(errstring);
end
nin = net.nin;
nhidden = net.nhidden;
nout = net.nout;

mark1 = nin*nhidden;
net.w1 = reshape(w(1:mark1), nin, nhidden);
mark2 = mark1 + nhidden;
net.b1 = reshape(w(mark1 + 1: mark2), 1, nhidden);
mark3 = mark2 + nhidden*nout;
net.w2 = reshape(w(mark2 + 1: mark3), nhidden, nout);
mark4 = mark3 + nout;
net.b2 = reshape(w(mark3 + 1: mark4), 1, nout);'
```

I tried different solutions that I could find on the net but none of them worked (like: using `coder.extrinsic('reshape')`, initializing `net.w1` with zeros ....)
Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide your build script?  It's possibly a problem with the declarations of the parameters.

Comment: Also, are you using 'extrinsic' in other places in your code? Could you provide the entire function?

Comment: As @Tony said, there is an extrinsic function call somewhere whose output is being indexed. [The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html#bq1h2z9-47) describes how to convert `mxArray` values (i.e. the output of extrinsic calls) to known types like `double` or `int32`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26096731/3297440) also describes the situation.

Comment: @Tony: I don't have any **build script**. How can I create, declare and  add a build script to my project? 
Here is what I am trying to compile:
The entry-point file contains a function with three inputs. I defined the type of input parameters in coder. Inside that function, I am calling other functions from a package that I got online (Netlab source code and the folder containing the package is added to matlab path) and those functions call other functions from the package.

Comment: As @lilbill39 notes, the `mxArray` type shows up from return values from functions declared extrinsic.  The answer he cites will show you how to make sure those variables are properly typed so you can use them.

Comment: @Tony : I added the entire code to the original post.

Comment: @lilbill39: I am not using **extrinsic** function call anywhere in the code. I am not sure if Coder  automatically uses them for unsupported functions.

Comment: You can export a build script from the MATLAB Coder user interface, which could be helpful to see what's going on here.  The UI is a good place to start with when building code, but it's generally useful to use the build scripts when diagnosing problems.

Comment: Check inside the `consist` function for any extrinsic calls too, as it's not a standard MATLAB function.  As far as I know, that's the only way to end up with mxArray types showing up, unless there's something in the input declarations.  In any case, the fix outlined in the answer @lilbill39 linked should handle your problem.

Comment: @AliJooya Some functions are called extrinsically automatically like graphics functions. An idea, run coder so the error occurs. Then, there should be a link somewhere that says "View error report" or "Open error report" either in the UI or in the command window. Click that to open the html report and find the red underlined location of the error in that report. Hover over the variable being indexed into to ensure it is an `mxArray`. Use the report to trace this variable back to its first assignment to see where the `mxArray` was introduced. You may have to trace it across function calls.

Comment: @AliJooya Looking at the entirety of the code, the only variable that is indexed is `w`. So you may want to look at it using the codegen report. It is possible that the `mxArray` is introduced in a function calling `mlpunpak`.

Comment: @lilbill39, Thanks to your suggestions, I fund the root of the problem. In my entry-file, I need to read some variables (matrices) from .m files. For Example, I have M1 stored in **Input.m** as follows:
'M1=[1 2 3
         4 5 6
        7 8 9];'
And I read it in my entry-file as follow:
'Input.m;'
To use the coder, I had to change that to  **coder.load()** which returns structure type. Copying part of that matrix into another variable make that variable of type **mxArray**. Any suggestion how to read variables stored in **.m** file as double?

Comment: @AliJooya I would recommend storing the data in a `MAT` file. So run `save data.mat M1` in MATLAB with `M1` defined. Then in your entry-point use `data = coder.load('data.mat'); M1 = data.M1;`. The `coder.load` usage does not need a `coder.extrinsic` declaration.